# Daoc can't connect to update server

Tags: dark-age-of-camelot

I just installed dark age of camelot, using disc. when i launched the game, a update window pop'd up. After 30 seconds it said cannot connect to update server (error 201).
i've heard someone say that there servers isn't up at weekends and at evening, but its midday here (GMT +1)

Comment: Are you sure its not the other way around? It seems strange to not run an MMO server during MMO peak hours, as in the weekends and evenings

Comment: yep pretty sure (thats what i heard)

Comment: @RustyMembers The official ea daoc servers are always online.

Comment: oh good i thought i was kind of weird to :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have installed Dark Age of Camelot from an old EU version of the game, but the host of the game [GOA closed the servers](http://daoc.goa.com/) a couple of years ago and that is why you can not connect, EU users should go to the US site to play.

I would suggest downloading the client from [the official site](http://www.darkageofcamelot.com/downloads) and connecting that way.

The following information is found on the US site for returning EU players:

> You can login to our Account Center using your old account login with
>   the extension "_eu" (for example "myname_eu") and your old password.
>   In case you have forgotten your password, you will be able to recover
>   your account information if you have access to the e-mail address you
>   originally used to create the account. Please contact Customer Support
>   if you are in need of assistance.

Comment: @Lawton Nonsens there are still loads of europeans playin Daoc aswell

Comment: how do i know if i have the EU version? cause im having this same issue... i only paid 6$ for this game at the local thift store and it looks like its never been played, the disk is beautiful and all of its stuff was still in the box including the poster which looks like i was the first to open it....